# How do I distribute distinguishable items to distinguishable groups with given criteria?

Tags: combinatorics

I want to distribute $n$ distinguishable items to $r$ distinguishable groups. However there are certain restrictions. Each group can have exactly one item. Items can be repeated. And no item can be left undistributed.

Since no item can be left undistributed, following should hold: $n\leq r$. For $n=r$, $n!$ is the desired count. I am struggling to come up with the closed formula for the desired count when $n<r$.

I applied following logic:

1. **Without using inclusion and exclusion**
   Each of $n$ items will appear at least once. This will take up $n$ positions out of $r$ and can be done in $\binom{r}{n}n!$ ways. Remaining $(r-n)$ positions can be taken up by any items, which can be done $(r-n)^n$ ways. So I felt the final count will be $\binom{r}{n}n!(r-n)^n$. However this seems to count certain distributions multiple times. How can I refine this formula to get correct final count?
2. **Using inclusion and exclusion**

   - Count such that any number of items left undistributed is $n^r$.
   - Count such that at least one item left undistributed is $\binom{n}{1}(n-1)^r$.
   - Count such that at least two item left undistributed is $\binom{n}{2}(n-2)^r$.
   - And so on.
   - By inclusion exclusion, we can get final count as $\binom{n}{0}(n-0)^r-\binom{n}{1}(n-1)^r+\binom{n}{3}(n-3)^r-...\pm\binom{n}{n}(n-n)^r=\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^i\binom{n}{i}(n-i)^r$
   - Even this count is giving wrong answers when I tried out some examples. For $n=2,r=3$, by using this formula, I get $$\binom{2}{0}(2)^3-\binom{2}{1}(1)^3+\binom{2}{2}(0)^3=8-2+1=7$$ But when I manually enumerate it, I get only six:
     {1,2,1},{2,1,2}
     {1,2,2},{2,1,1}
     {1,1,2},{2,2,1}
     How can I refine this equation to give correct result?

Or am I completely wrong in both approaches?

Comment: You said ["]each group has exactly one item[."] and ["]no item left undistributed[."], so should I conclude that: $n=r$?

Comment: Or you meant "n distinguishable *type* of items", so each type may have more than one items? So ["]Items can be repeated["] is reasonable?

Comment: I think a concrete example about the question should be good!

Comment: Hello, your last formula is okay except that actually $\tbinom22(0)^3=0$. You might want to google "Stirling numbers of the second kind" for more information.

Comment: @Niing it can be very well $n<r$. Note that I also said that repetitions are allowed. I have given the example, in which $n=2,r=3$, so that $n<r$. Also, we have distinguishable items and groups in that example.

Comment: @AndrewWoods Stirling number of 2nd kind does no apply here. I know about it. Stirling formula is applied when repetition of items is not allowed, [groups are indistinguishable](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=IQ2jAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA377) & each group contains one or more items. Here repetition is allowed, groups are distinguishable and each groups contains exactly one item. Also note that Stirling number of second kind is $S(n,r)=\frac{1}{r!}\sum_{i=0}^{r-1}(-1)^i\binom{r}{i}(r-i)^n$, whereas in 2nd approach I have got $\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^i\binom{n}{i}(n-i)^r$, which I guess is $n!\times S(r,n)$.

Comment: (...continued) note third count (above we have two, the one in question which is $n!\times S(r,n)$ and the one in above comment $S(n,r)$) which can be given in terms of Stirling number of 2nd kind is [number of onto functions](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=yJIMx9nXB6kC&pg=PA111) from set of $n$ distinguishable items to $r$ distinguishable groups, where each group can contain one or more items, repetitions are not allowed and is given as $r!\times S(n,r)$

Comment: (...continued) The two $S(n,r)$ and $r!\times S(n,r)$ are discussed in books. But, the one in question ($n!\times S(r,n)$) is not discussed in any book. (Also I know $\binom{2}{2}(0)^3=0$) So want someone to confirm if its correct.

Comment: @AndrewWoods am I wrong with above comments? Also, dont you think that the count $n! \times S(r,n)$ which I have come up in original question is wrong if we look at the example given in it?

Comment: Your second approach was right. The formula $n!\cdot S(r,n)$ is correct. Your problem is equivalent to distributing $r$ objects into $n$ indistinguishable bags, leaving none empty, and then labelling the bags (which is why $n!$ appears). Note that in the equivalent problem, the items have become bags, and the groups have become objects.

Comment: Then where did I mistake in the example (last bullet point in 2nd approach)? By formula, I get 7 distributions, but by manually listing, I get 6 distributions. Can you please point out?

Comment: With respect, I pointed out in my first response that $\tbinom22(0)^3=1\cdot 0=0$ and not $1$. You even repeated the statement in one of your replies. So the correct calculation is not $8-2+1=7$ but $8-2+0=6$, which is the result you found by making the list. That small arithmetical mistake misled you into supposing the formula was wrong.

Comment: Cant say enough how pissed I am now for that small mistake and wasting so much time...

Comment: I'm sorry. Most likely my first response was just not clear enough. One must remember that it is very hard in combinatorics to avoid mistakes and it is necessary to check and recheck all calculations.